# uninitialized constant error in rails 3 on newly created controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I added a Session controller to my application for user sign-in / sign-out, using

> rails g controller Session new create destroy

then add the following lines to my route file:

> resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
>        match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
>        match '/signin', :to => 'sessions#new'
>        match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

when I do `rake routes` in the console, the routes do show up, but when I launch the app in the browser, I got this error:

> uninitialized constant SessionsController

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You created a `Session` controller, not a `Sessions` controller. Since it's singular, you want a singular route:

```
resource :session, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

Comment: also singular on the session_path?

Comment: I would think so but you can verify that by running rake routes and looking at the first column of the output for the resources of interest. If you append _path to the end of those things you get the variable name.

Comment: @vinc386 Yes; you can also see what routes are available via `rake routes`.

Comment: thanks, im always confused by these singular/plural conventions

Answer (score 3):

I was running into this today, and found I had to do three things, 1) use resource (not resources); 2) supply the controller manually, and 3) manually set the url in form_for tags using the resource (may not apply for your case)...

```
# routes.rb
resource :session, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy], :controller => 'session'

#.../new.html.erb
<% form_for @session, :url => session_path do |f| %>
```

Specifying the controller matters if, like me, your controller name, file names, etc, are all singular.

This is apparently related to a [bug in rails](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/267)